# How can I animate HTML divs to transition up smoothly when a sibling is removed?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, animate.css

**What I want to achieve:**

I'm working on a CSS/JS animation on my page.

Fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/hngz8rq4/

**The HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="mock-requests">
    <div class="mock-request">
      <div class="mock-request-inner">
      </div>
      <small>Box 1</small>
    </div>

    <div class="mock-request">
      <div class="mock-request-inner">
      </div>
      <small>Box 2</small>
    </div>

    <div class="mock-request">
      <div class="mock-request-inner">
      </div>
      <small>Box 3</small>      
    </div>

    <div class="mock-request">
      <div class="mock-request-inner">
      </div>
      <small>Box 4</small>      
    </div>

    <div class="mock-request">
      <div class="mock-request-inner">
      </div>
      <small>Box 5</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
var mockRequests;

mockRequests = (function() {
  var animationStep0, animationStep1, animationStep2, callNextStep, init, itemHeight, startTimer, step, timeDelay, timer;
  timer = null;
  step = 0;
  timeDelay = 1600;
  itemHeight = 0;
  init = function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.mock-request')) {
      $(".mock-request").addClass('animated');
      itemHeight = $('.mock-request:first').css('height');
      return startTimer();
    }
  };
  startTimer = function() {
    return timer = setInterval(callNextStep, timeDelay);
  };
  animationStep0 = function() {
    $('.mock-request:first').addClass('checked');
    return step += 1;
  };
  animationStep1 = function() {
    $('.mock-request:first').addClass('zoomOutLeft');
    return step += 1;
  };
  animationStep2 = function() {
    console.log("Setting item height: " + itemHeight);
    $('.mock-request.checked').removeClass('checked zoomOutLeft').remove().css({
      "height": itemHeight
    }).appendTo('.mock-requests').addClass('zoomInBottom');
    return step = 0;
  };
  callNextStep = function() {
    return eval("animationStep" + step + "()");
  };
  return {
    init: init
  };
})();

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", mockRequests.init);
```

**The CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}
small {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8rem;
  left: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
.mock-request {
  position: relative;
  height: 3rem;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.mock-request:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6rem;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f10c";
}
.mock-request.checked:before {
  content: "\f058";
}

.mock-request-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  height: 0;
  width: 80%;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.container {
  background-color: black;
}
```

The effect I want to recreate is similar to the swipe-to-delete effect on iOS. I want it to look like an element in the stack is being checked, and then swiped left to get rid of it.

Once an item is removed, the stack should gracefully slide up to take the place of the previous first item.

This sequence should loop continuously.

For efficiency, I take the dismissed first item from the stack and append it to the bottom of the stack again.

**The problem:**

At the moment, once I remove the top element from the stack, the rest of them jump up to take the place of the earlier sibling. I would like this transition to happen slowly (~0.8s) rather than instantly, as it's doing now.

Can anybody suggest an elegant way to complete this sequence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at your interesting issue, and I think I have an answer, jQuery animations which you can see referenced here - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The reason for your problem is that based on your CSS positions, until that item is removed, it is taking up that content, and thus when it is removed, the other div takes up the space automatically.

So, the best way I can see is to modify the height of that div being removed. I added another case statement to achieve this.
"
      case 2:
        $( ".mock-song-request:first" ).animate({"height":"0px"},"slow");
        return step += 1;
"

So, in reducing its height, the below div will appear to scroll up smoothly. The use of "slow" is just a favourite of mine from my game-engine building days, but as the API documentation states, you can specify milliseconds

Unfortunately, jSFiddle doesn't contain the right version of jQuery to let that example show my working example, but I have been able to get it to work as expected on a local file.